# How is the :assets group in rails 3.1 handled by bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I don't understand what exactly is going on with this group, and what bundler is doing with it. Is it only loaded in dev mode? What if I want to make a new environment type, how should I handle this group? Etc.

```
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The code that handles `:assets` group placed in `config\application.rb`. In rails 3.1 it is:

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

Answer (score 8):

To elaborate a little on the answer, from [rails asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#upgrading-from-old-versions-of-rails):

a) by default they are NOT included in production:

```
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
```

b) If you add a new environment type, you would want to handle it according to Dmitry's answer above.  That is, add it as one of the groups that will require it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be,

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

because there are some warning with the line,

```
Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
```

So we use,

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
```

Hope this helps :)-