# Heroku assets precompilation and gem memory usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, memory-management, heroku, rubygems

I read in this amazing [article](http://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/how-to-get-more-bang-for-your-heroku-buck-while-making-your-rails-site-super-snappy-redux) that I should save my RAM by adding gems to the `:assets` group.

So I tried to do that:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.5.0'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

  # Front-end
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'
end
```

But then I get this error, when pushing to heroku:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Me#index

Showing /app/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml where line #58 raised:

couldn't find file 'jquery'
  (in /app/app/assets/javascripts/libs/libs.js:4)
Extracted source (around line #58):

55: 
56:   / %script{src: "//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.4.0/mapbox.js"}
57: 
58:   = javascript_include_tag 'libs/libs'
59:   %script{:src => "http://js.pusher.com/2.1/pusher.min.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
60:   %script{:src => "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/modernizr/2.7.1/modernizr.min.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
61:   %script{:src => "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.11.0/polyfiller.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
```

And I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351607/how-is-the-assets-group-in-rails-3-1-handled-by-bundler) that it is normal, as :assets means pretty much :development + :test

How can I tell Heroku that I'd like a specific gem to be loaded on assets precompilation, but not during runtime anymore?

I use Rails 3.2.

Thanks for support

Comment: What version of Rails are using? Also where at the assets located? This can cause problems too. Just as a future FYI the assets group has been removed in Rails 4.

You can use the :production, :development, :testing groups to organize the gems and keep dev gems from being bundled into your production application.

Comment: Using Rails 3.2. I read it was removed in Rails 4. But I'm not sure I understand the point the `:assets` group if it is not to precompile them before going to production. Is there a possibility to mention that these gems are only necessary at this step, and not on runtime?

Comment: regardless I don't think the problem is in your gem file. Have you checked your application.js to make sure jQuery is listed in this file?

Comment: Yes, it is: earlier and now again, I moved the jQuery gem out of the `:assets` group and it's working again.